# How Can I Improve Line Detection Accuracy when Analyzing Images for Extending Arms from Object Centers in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am attempting to identify projected lines from the center of the object, as depicted in the images below.

[image: img1] [image: img2]

[image: img3] [image: img4]

So far, I have tried filling the object after finding its contour, then extracting the skeleton of the filled image and applying the Hough Line Transform to count the number of lines, as shown in the images below.

[image: img5]

[image: img6]

[image: img7]

However, this approach has not yielded the desired results. Below is the code I am currently using for this task.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from skimage.transform import hough_line, hough_line_peaks
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from skimage import color
from imutils import paths 
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize


# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("image.PNG")


plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1])
plt.show()

thickness = 5

# Get image dimensions
height, width = img.shape[:2]

# Define border dimensions
top = bottom = thickness
left = right = thickness

# Create border mask
border_mask = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)  # Ensure the mask has the same number of channels as the image
border_mask[top:height-bottom, left:width-right] = 255

# Add thickness to edges of image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, border_mask)

# Add black border
result = cv2.copyMakeBorder(result, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0,0,0)) 
# Convert the image to grayscale (if it's not already)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply thresholding
_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours in the thresholded image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Draw the contours on a copy of the original image
contour_image = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(contour_image, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), 40)
# Taking a matrix of size 5 as the kernel
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

img_dilation = cv2.dilate(contour_image, kernel, iterations=10)

# Bitwise AND operation to fill the image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img_dilation)

plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()


skeleton = skeletonize(result)

image = cv2.cvtColor(skeleton, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Classic straight-line Hough transform
# Set a precision of 0.05 degree.
tested_angles = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 180)

h, theta, d = hough_line(image, theta=tested_angles)
hpeaks = hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d, threshold=0.2 * h.max())
print(len(hpeaks[0]))

plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')
# display the skeletonized image
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(skeleton, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
axes.set_title('Skeleton of the image')
plt.show()

skeleton_copy = skeleton.copy()

for _, angle, dist in zip(*hpeaks):
    a = np.cos(angle)
    b = np.sin(angle)
    x0 = a * dist
    y0 = b * dist
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))
    cv2.line(skeleton_copy, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)

plt.imshow(skeleton_copy)
plt.show()
```

Is there a better approach to achieve my goal?" ANy help or suggestion on this will be highly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to go with a *RANSAC* approach (*[Random sample consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus)*). *RANSAC* will give you the pixels and equation of
straight lines in your image, while being robust to noise. *OpenCV2* has a ransac function with python bindings.

So in short,

1. Use *RANSAC* iteratively to find lines, until you run out of white pixels.
2. Remove the lines that have similar angles (only keep one)
3. print the remaining lines based on their coefficients (ax+b) provided by the *RANSAC* function.

You can find a tutorial about using *RANS*AC for the specific case of finding lines here: *[Sequential RANSAC approach](https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/recursive-ransac-approach-to-find-all-straight-lines-in-an-image-b5c510a0224a)*

Answer (score 0):

Scanning only border of the image to find locations of yellow pixels. Then...

- If employing some clustering method, number of lines will be able to be counted.
- And/Or you can track the yellow pixels from image border to center direction. This result will be useful to extract line's info (region, parameter).