# How can I find the center point of the intersecting lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Im trying to find center point of line joining as shown in below image
[image: src img]

as shown below

[image: src img2]

I tried below approach but im not able to find a logic to find the exact location of joining lines

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import hough_line, hough_line_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError
from imutils import paths 
get_all_imgs = list(paths.list_images(r"img.png"))

for img_f in get_all_imgs:
# Load the image
img = cv2.imread(img_f)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = np.array([26, 0, 0])
upper_blue = np.array([52, 255, 255])
hsvmask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

# Perform Hough Transform to detect lines
h, theta, d = hough_line(hsvmask)

# Function to find intersection of two lines
def intersection(line1, line2):
    rho1, theta1 = line1
    rho2, theta2 = line2
    A = np.array([
        [np.cos(theta1), np.sin(theta1)],
        [np.cos(theta2), np.sin(theta2)]
    ])
    b = np.array([[rho1], [rho2]])
    try:
        x0, y0 = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
        x0, y0 = int(np.round(x0)), int(np.round(y0))
        return [x0, y0]
    except LinAlgError:
        return None

# Find intersections
intersections = []
lines = list(zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)))
for i, line1 in enumerate(lines):
    for line2 in lines[i+1:]:
        if line1 != line2:
            intersect = intersection((line1[2], line1[1]), (line2[2], line2[1]))
            if intersect is not None:
                intersections.append(intersect)

# Find the intersection point with the shortest distance to the origin
distances = [np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) for x, y in intersections]
min_distance_index = np.argmin(distances)
min_distance_point = intersections[min_distance_index]

# Plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
ax.imshow(hsvmask, cmap=cm.gray)
for _, angle, dist in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    (x0, y0) = dist * np.array([np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)])
    ax.axline((x0, y0), slope=np.tan(angle + np.pi/2), color='red')

# Plot the intersection point with the shortest distance
ax.plot(min_distance_point[0], min_distance_point[1], 'bo')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which gives me output as

[image: outp]

any help or suggestion to solve this will be helpful

Comment: context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188372/how-can-i-improve-line-detection-accuracy-when-analyzing-images-for-extending-ar

Comment: sounds like you could frame that as a optmization problem (minimization). find the point that has the least distance to all lines. the gradients for that seem very tame. if you'd like me to give an answer, I'll need a list of lines.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  Hi thanks for suggestions, I would like to know your answer , you can find list of lines with lines = list(zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)))

Comment: Instead of the Hough transform, you could easily isolate lines using connected component analysis (labeling), then find (using least squares or RANSAC) the best fit line to each object. Then you have a single line per object instead of multiple. Finding the intersection point of two lines is a trivial exercise. You could find the intersection of each pair and then average the results, or directly find the least squares solution as suggested in the answer by aerobiomat below.

Answer (score 3):

If you define the lines in cartesian coordinates (a,b,c), where ax+by+c=0, for example:

```
>>> lines = np.array([[1,0,-1], [1,0,-3], [-1,1,-1], [-1,1,3]])
```

You can define an overdetermined linear system Ax=B as:

```
>>> A = lines[:, :2]
>>> B = -lines[:, 2]
```

And (approximately) solve it using [lstsq()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) to obtain the closest point to all lines:

```
>>> np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]
array([2., 1.])
```